# Spring cloud ZUUL Configuration in yml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I want to configure **ZUUL** properties in **application.yml** file but somehow i am not able to define the routes in the **yml** file(i get page not found in browser). It works perfectly in **application.properties** file though. Below are the properties in `application.properties` and `application.yml` file.

**application.properties**

```
#subway is the application context name of a microservice. This works perfectly fine.
zuul.routes.**subway**.url=http://localhost:7777/
```

**applcation.yml file**

```
zuul:
  routes:
    subway:
      path: /subway/**
      url: http://localhost:7777/
```

Also Tried :

```
zuul:
  routes:
      service-id: /subway/**
      path: /subway/**
      url: "http://localhost:7777/"
      strip-prefix: false
      service-id: /subway1/**
      path: /subway1/**
      strip-prefix: false
      url: "http://localhost:6666/"
      service-id: /subway2/**
      path: /subway2/**
      url: "http://localhost:5555/"
      strip-prefix: false
```

I get exception

> Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing
>   MappingNode  in 'reader', line 12, column 7:
>             service-id: /subway/**

Is there anything i have missed?

Comment: Can you try this with double quotes? `url: "http://localhost:7777/"`

Comment: in yml??........

Comment: yeah........... in yml

Comment: not working bruh ..

Comment: what isn't working? Still getting page not found?

Comment: Try this `zuul:
  routes:
     path: http://localhost:7777/
     service-id: **subway**
     strip-prefix: false`

Comment: yeah same issue... subway is context-path.... which is running in port 7777. If i define the same property in application.properties file i dont get page not found. But in yml i am getting.

Comment: @pvkiran : what is service-id ?

Comment: It is the service name. edited my comment. check it out

Comment: I tried that but i got compile time exception. I have updated by question with the exception @pvpkiran

Comment: If `url: http://localhost:7777/` is a complete value, can you try `"url: http://localhost:7777/"`? I suspect it is something to do with `yml` rather `zuul`

Comment: Thank you both of you for helping me out..

Answer (score 2):

Below is how it should work. Thank You @harshavmb and @pvpkiran :

```
zuul:
  routes:
    subway:
      service-id: /subway/**
      path: /subway/**
      url: "http://localhost:7777/"
      strip-prefix: false
    subway1:
      service-id: /subway1/**
      path: /subway1/**
      strip-prefix: false
      url: "http://localhost:6666/"
    subway2:
      service-id: /subway2/**
      path: /subway2/**
      url: "http://localhost:5555/"
      strip-prefix: false
```

Comment: How can I map an application.properties like the following: `zuul.routes.student.url=http://localhost:8090
#Will start the gateway server @8080
server.port=8080` in a .yml file?